# php count xml elements isn't work fine when there is one element

Tags: php, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array

I have a problem in counting `xml` elements. Let's see an example.

```
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>first</name>
    <url>test1</url>
  </product>
  <product>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>second</name>
    <url>test1</url>
  </product>
</products>
```

**In php:** For this example it counts fine:

```
count($array['products']['product']);
// This gives me 2
```

But when I have only **one** product:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>first</name>
    <url>test1</url>
  </product>
</products>
```

Now in php:

```
count($array['products']['product']);
// This gives me 3 , number of sub elements of product (It must be 1)
//(because in this case we have one product and there is no sub array for counting,
//so instead of another product, features of product is counting)
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

I can use `count($array['products']);` when there is only one product. That's ok. BUT, I check the xml in a loop. How should I know whether it has one product or not? At first I must can count the product.

Comment: that's because `$array['products']['product']` is a shortcut for `$array['products'][0]` - you're counting the elements inside the FIRST product node of the main array['products'], not the number of arr/product/product nodes.

Comment: @MarcB No, you are wrong. It's work when there are more than one product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made a solution: I must check whether `product` is multidimensional array or not.

**In first case:**

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    ([id]=>1...)
  [1] => Array
    ([id]=>2...)
)
```

**In Second case:**

```
Array
(
  [id]=>1...
)
```

Now I wrote a function to check whether it's multidimensional array or not. If the array is not multidimensional, so the **count is one!**

```
public function isMultiArray($arr){
    foreach ($arr as $key) {
        if (is_array($key)) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to just count($array['products']);

Comment: That's ok. BUT, I check the xml in a loop. How should I know whether it has one product or not? At first I must can count the product.

Comment: Counting $array['products'] will give you the number of elements in that array, which will be the number of products, looking at your structure....

Comment: I found the solution, thanks. (please see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explain how you are deriving the array initially butI assume via `DOMDocument`? In which case you should be able to deduce the length / count using a method like this.

```
$strxml='<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>first</name>
    <url>test1</url>
  </product>
</products>';


$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $strxml );

$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('product');
if( is_object( $col ) ){
    echo $col->length;  
}
$col=$dom=null;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I made a solution and you can see in answers.

Answer (score 1):

it's unclear how you transformed the XML into that array.

If you parse the XML directly with `SimpleXml`, `count()` will give accurate results:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
echo $xml->product->count();
```

Comment: I'm not working with `object`. At first, I transformed the XML into the `json` , then decoded it in an array. I solved my problem. check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36023531/4055329

Answer (score 0):

Your XML code is not well formed. The closing `</product>` - tag for product 1 is missing. In the 2nd example you have two `<product>` open tags but no closing one.

Comment: Sorry, it was just a typing issue.

Comment: I found the solution, thanks. (please see my answer)